# Django (drf) add new parameters/fields only for output with existing queryset(used for output) from database

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-serializer

I am working on a project on drf, where I need to fetch data from database (in thousands), and display selective fields in response.

models.py

```
class TblDemo(models.Model):
    tbl_id = models.IntegerField()
    tbl_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tbl_size = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tbl_height = models.Charfield(max_length=50)
    tbl_material = models.Charfield(max_length=50)

    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'tbl_demo'
```

views.py

```
class data_fetch(viewsets.ViewSet):
    def tbl_list(self, request, format=None)
        serializer = Tbl_Serializer_input(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            queryset1 = tbl_name.objects.all()
            queryset2 = queryset1.filter(tbl_name=request.data.get("title"))
            serializer = Tbl_Serializer_output(queryset2, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data)
```

serializers.py

```
class Tbl_Serializer_input(serializers.Serializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)
    refer_no = serializers.CharField(required=True, max_length=50)

class Tbl_Serializer_output(serializers.Serializer):
    tbl_id = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    tbl_name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    tbl_size = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    tbl_height = serializers.Charfield(max_length=50)
```

output

```
[
  {
    "tbl_id":"1", 
    "tbl_name":"white table",
    "tbl_size": "square",
    "tbl_height": "2 feet"
  },
  {
    "tbl_id":"2", 
    "tbl_name":"black table",
    "tbl_size": "square",
    "tbl_height": "3 feet"
  },
  .......and so on.
```

but now, requirement is that I can't change database/model, but need to add some more fields like ("refer_no", "material" and "density", which is overall same in every cases) and  with every object in queryset, which will not be stored in database, but it is only for response/output.

so, after adding new parameters my output will be like :
where, "refer_no" is taken directly from input to show output fields.
and "material" and "density" can't be added in database, just need to be hardcoded in middle.

new_output

```
[
  {
    "tbl_id":"1", 
    "refer_no":"abadadf",
    "tbl_name":"white table",
    "tbl_size": "square",
    "tbl_height": "2 feet",
    "density": "350gm/in"
    "material": "tek wood"
  },
  {
    "tbl_id":"2", 
    "refer_no":"abadadf",
    "tbl_name":"black table",
    "tbl_size": "square",
    "tbl_height": "3 feet",
    "density": "350gm/in",
    "material": "tek wood"
  },
  .......and so on.
```

I have actually added new fields with query set from database, but when it went for serialization, it is showing circular loop error.

Please help.

Comment: have you tried `ReadOnlyField` in serializers

Comment: I think you need [this](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield). In this method you have access to `self.request` so you have access to input data.

Answer (score 1):

You could process the data inside the serializer using the `to_representation` method.

For instance:

```py
class ModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        to_repr = super().to_representation(instance)
        # add here the "refer_no", "material" and "density" key-value per object
        return to_repr
```